Missing form information in ASP.NET Core
I have a series of form inputs with the same name (columnFilter) which when empty are not described in the form collection in my ASP.NET Core code
My request form payload as show in network tools is as follows
searchInput:
page: 1
exportformat: csv
columnFilter: 8
columnFilter:
columnFilter:
columnFilter: 66
currentSortKey: 1542182193
currentSortAscending: True
model: 0YjjzoiQiO3....

But when I inspect the form value for columnFilter in IFormCollection it shows me "8,66" what I would really like to see is "8,,,66". That is, let me know that the 2nd and 3rd columnFilter values are empty. I can't see a way to get that information ?

it'll bind multiple of the same (whether query params in GET or in POSTed data) to a List.  The behavior here I think has to do with convertEmptyStringsToNull.  You can set the field in the model to not convert to null by using this:  [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]  Haven't tried this with a list binding but worth a shot.

The first way is that you could put these parameters in the model and use [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)] attribute:
public class TestVM
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public List<string> columnFilter { get; set; }
   //other properties...
}

Get the value in controller:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ProcessForm(TestVM model)
{
    // ColumnFilter will include empty strings
    var columnFilters = string.Join(",", model.columnFilter); // Example output: "8,,,66"
    //.....
}

The second way is that you could access the Request.Form and manually parse the values, including empty ones.
var columnFilters = Request.Form["columnFilter"];
var filters = new List<string>();

foreach (var key in Request.Form.Keys)
{
    if (key == "columnFilter")
    {
        //add the value to the filters list including empty ones
        filters.AddRange(Request.Form[key].ToArray());
    }
}
var result = string.Join(",", filters);

The third way is that you could do the convert logic in custom model binding:
public class CustomFormCollectionModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var form = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;
        var formCollection = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();

        foreach (var key in form.Keys)
        {
            if (key == "columnFilter")
            {
                var serializedValue = string.Join(",", form[key].ToArray());
                formCollection[key] = serializedValue;
            }
            else
            {
                formCollection.Add(key, form[key]);
            }
        }

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(new FormCollection(formCollection));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Custom model binding usage in controller:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ProcessForm([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomFormCollectionModelBinder))] IFormCollection form)
{
    //....
}


Thanks for all the suggestions. The key piece I was missing was call ToArray on the form value as that filled out the empty slots in the array i.e  Request.Form["ColumnFilter"].ToArray()
